# Find poly1d Solutions for a Specified Complex Number

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

Imagine I have a `np.poly1d` function: `5 x^2 + 2 x + 1`. How do I produce all complex solutions `5 x^2 + 2 x + 1 == a`, where `a` is another parameter input?

The examples I've seen just play with altering the functions, themselves, or give outputs when inserting inputs for the variable in the `poly1d` function (i.e., the output of `5 a^2 + 2 a + 1`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is very simple, numpy will create another instance for you when you put it in math operation:

```py
>>> f = np.poly1d([5,2,1])
>>> a = 2                       # number
>>> b = [1, -2]                 # list
>>> c = np.array([-4, -4, -4])  # numpy array
>>> 
>>> f
poly1d([5, 2, 1])
>>> f-a
poly1d([ 5,  2, -1]
>>> f-b
poly1d([5, 1, 3])
>>> f+c
poly1d([ 1, -2, -3])
>>> 
>>> f.roots                     # roots of f(x) = 0
array([-0.2+0.4j, -0.2-0.4j])
>>> (f-a).roots                 # roots of f(x) - 2 = 0
array([-0.68989795,  0.28989795])
>>> (f-b).roots                 # roots of f(x) - (1x - 2) = 0
array([-0.1+0.76811457j, -0.1-0.76811457j])
>>> (f+c).roots                 # roots of f(x) + (-4x^2 - 4x - 4) = 0
array([ 3., -1.])
```

However, this will throw error if you try with array that has dimension greater than 1, since this is a 1d function.

```py
>>> d = np.array([[1], [2]])
>>> (f-d).roots
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 1291, in __sub__
    other = poly1d(other)
  File "\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 1171, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Polynomial must be 1d only.")
ValueError: Polynomial must be 1d only.
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If the formula is `5 x^2 + 2x + 1`, and `a` is 8, the output should be `[-1.4, 1]`. If you know how to produce these outputs, I'd be happy to switch my vote to an upvote and check it as the correct answer.

Comment: @JoshuaHarwood in my example, i set `a = 2`. Just simply change it to `a = 8` and run `(f-a).roots` as above. I get the expected result. [online demo](https://trinket.io/python3/8263a7c58c).  What is your output ?

Comment: I marked the answer as the right one. If you make an edit to the post reflecting that, StackOverflow will let me switch my vote, as well.